# Finding invalid 0000-00-00 dates on mysql database

Tags: mysql, date, mode, strict

We are moving our mysql database to strict_all_tables from non-strict mode and would like to find all existing rows with invalid dates (0000-00-00) from all databases and tables on our server. Is there a way to do this by one command or some other simple way?

I would like to know database and table name where the 0000-00-00 value exists, column name would be a plus.

We have quite a large amount of databases with a large set of tables, some containing quite a large amount of data so the more automatic the method, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#kedar.nitty-witty.com

## Table for storing resultant output
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_details`;
CREATE TABLE `temp_details` ( 
`t_schema` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`t_table` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`t_field` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



## Procedure for search in all fields of all databases
DELIMITER $$
#Script to loop through all tables using Information_Schema
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_table(in_search varchar(50))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE trunc_cmd VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE search_string VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE db,tbl,clmn CHAR(50);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE COUNTER INT;
DECLARE table_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT concat('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @CNT_VALUE FROM `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` WHERE `', column_name,'` REGEXP "',in_search,'"') ,table_schema,table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema','test','mysql');
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
#Truncating table for refill the data for new search.
PREPARE trunc_cmd FROM "TRUNCATE TABLE temp_details;";
EXECUTE trunc_cmd ; 
OPEN table_cur;
table_loop:LOOP
FETCH table_cur INTO search_string,db,tbl,clmn;
#Executing the search
SET @search_string = search_string;
##SELECT  search_string;
PREPARE search_string FROM @search_string;
EXECUTE search_string;
SET COUNTER = @CNT_VALUE;
##SELECT COUNTER;
IF COUNTER>0 THEN
# Inserting required results from search to table
INSERT INTO temp_details VALUES(db,tbl,clmn);
END IF;
IF done=1 THEN
LEAVE table_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE table_cur;
#Finally Show Results
SELECT * FROM temp_details;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanky you, the procedure version (forge.mysql.com link) seems to work just as I wanted.

Comment: [Here is a quick direct link to create procedure sql](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/find-in-all-databases-tables.sql_.txt) just in case someone wants to use this too

Comment: @redmoon7777, Can we replace zero dates across database, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23385555/1431250

Comment: When doing (from a `test` database): `call test.get_table('findme');`, it returns: `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION test.extract_table_from_file_name does not exist`.   This seems to be an error seeing: [extract_table_from_file_name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-extract-table-from-file-name.html)