# Changing MySQL server mode

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am about to change MySQL production DB mode to [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). MySQL would not allow zero date insert/update in the new mode.

My tables do have, zero dates in format `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` will those rows be affected?

Comment: Already existing rows will not be affected.

Comment: @jdiver Can I force MySQL to update all zero rows, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23385555/1431250